# Keep the fix price for configurable Product while choosing the attribute also but change for second place

Tags: magento

In my site i am using configurable product and Price is showing at two different place in Product page. One is near product and one is at bottom of all details and i am giving label as "new subtotal". And the both price is changing based on what attribute i am selecting but what i want is to change price at one place only at bottom "New subtotal" label and i want to keep top price is fix even changing the attribute. I tried by doing some changes in view.phtml file to get price using getPrice() but it giving me the fix price at both places. Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using magento default code in view.phtml then there will be code `<?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>` which display price with html.

In stead of above, just use `$_product->getPrice()` to display price without default magento html.

Hop this will help.

Comment: No actually still it is changing price at both place.

Comment: send me link.. if live running on any server